# Can kali linux be hacked

Tags: kali-linux

I'm just curious if new version of backtrack Kali be hacked like back-doored or crack user password like the windows or mac

Comment: Poster seems to be unclear on the actual meanings of the terms he's using...

Comment: Hey in this world every technical thing is hack-able

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be hacked.  No OS (outside of some limited micro kernels) has proven perfect security.  It is theoretically possible to do, but nobody has done it and even then, there would be know way to know it is implemented after the proof without building it yourself from the individual circuits on up.  It's not possible to know if there are any active backdoors for sure since they could be subtle, even encryption could possibly (though unlikely) have a back door.

Outside of encryption, with physical access, any system can be read directly off the hard drive and configuration information can be replaced to simply change a user.  If encryption is used and the encryption itself isn't back doored (and is properly implemented) it should require the password to access even if there is a backdoor in the OS itself.  (The password should be a key piece of information for generating the actual decryption key.)

Comment: I agree. There is not such thing as a human-made invulnerable computing system.

Comment: Small nitpick, but there is some other software that is formally verified besides seL4 and INTEGRITY (assuming those are the ones you were talking about), such as miTLS and HTTP.sys of IIS.

Comment: @forest great point and a bad word choice on my part.  I meant os rather than software, though I suppose one can argue that any software running on an unproven os is not proven perfect security, but I guess that's similar to my hardware argument for seL4.